# Chrome-cast app crashes after casting to the TV

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

I am modifying [CastAndroid-Videos](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) app such that instead of appearing list from JSON request, I put textbox which accepts any url of video to be casted on TV.

So according to that I modified `VideoBrowserListFragment.java` as follows

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflator,ViewGroup container,Bundle saveInstanceState)
{
View v=inflator.inflate(R.layout.videourl, container,false);

mm=new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);
mm.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE, "Some text");
mm.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "Some string");
mm.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_STUDIO, "Something");
mm.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse("Some image URL")));
mm.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse("Some image URL")));

submit=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.submit);
url=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.texturl);
submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        info=new MediaInfo.Builder(url.getText().toString())
            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
            .setContentType("video/mp4")
            .setMetadata(mm)
            .build();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Info:"+info.getContentId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LocalPlayerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("media", Utils.fromMediaInfo(info));
        intent.putExtra("shouldStart", false);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
});


return v;
```

}

But after Casting to TV, app gets crash while video keeps on playing on TV. While testing I am not having my host machine so I can't put log cat.

I am not changing anything throughout whole app. So cam anybody tell me where am I going wrong??

Comment: Why don't you debug your issue yourself? If it shows error dialog, track it down and see where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to copy these functions to your class: buildMediaInfo and handleNavigation.
On submit do this:

```
String url = ... //get url from textbox

//
MediaInfo selectedMedia = buildMediaInfo("custom video",
                        "none", "none", url, link_to_some_image, link_to_some_big_image);
handleNavigation(selectedMedia, false);
```

That is everything you need. In this way, you will acquire URL of the video which must be stored on some server. link_to_some_image is optional, you can provide any image, for example, a chromecast logo. 
Handle navigation will start LocalPlayerActivity and that is it.
This works for me.